# TypeError: selector.split is not a function with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I´m very new to cypress and I´m trying to automate a few things with it. I have a list of elements which have the same class and I want to get the length of my list. I´ve tried a few things but it didn´t work. Last try was:

```
cy.get('.product').its('length').should('be', 12)
```

I get the error: 
TypeError: selector.split is not a function

Any hints as to what I´m doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, chai supports the length keyword:

```js
cy.get('.product').should('have.length', 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that way easier:

```
cy.get('. product')
  .should($productCount => {
    expect($productCount)
      .to.have.length(12)
  })
```

Using Chai you have access to the .to.have.length methods.